# How to Automate Time Picker on Android 5.0 using Appium Java

Tags: java, android, mobile, automation, appium

I need to automate the Android 5.0 Native Time Picker to select a time parameterized.

[image: Android 5.0 Native Time Picker]

I have searched in several threads and blogs, but I can not find a way to do this.

I have tried with this,

```
androidDriver.findElement(By.name("6")).click();
androidDriver.findElement(By.name("45")).click();
```

But it will give an error like below.

[image: Error log]

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.jsp

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but If you need to set a time in a time picker you can do something like:
`TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
timePicker.setHour(hour);
timePicker.setMinute(minute);`
Is that what you need?

Comment: @MaxPower: Actually you are referring to the development, What I need to know is how to automate the time picker in Android 5.0

Comment: What do you mean by automate?

Comment: @MaxPower: Using an Automation script, I need to set the time for the time picker. I am using Appium for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using findElementByAccessibilityId

```
androidDriver.findElementByAccessibilityId("6").click();
```